# Как двигать элементы списка вниз?

Tags: вёрстка

[image: Нужно сделать отступы как в макете]

**[image: Не получается сделать отступы элементов]**

```css
.procent {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: #4d4d4d;
 margin-left: 190px;
 margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
            <ul class="procent" >
              <li>
                <h4>100%</h4>
              </li>
              <li>
                <h4>90%</h4>
              </li>
              <li>
                <h4>80%</h4>
              </li>
              <li>
                <h4>70%</h4>
              </li>
              <li>
                <h4>60%</h4>
              </li>
              <li>
                <h4>50%</h4>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
```

Comment: margin-bottom: 50px;

Comment: Не работают не margin не padding

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, я взял класс "procent" и пристроил к нему элемент списка li;
`.procent li {
   margin-bottom: 50px;
}`

Comment: могу показать как весь этот график сделать

Comment: @MaximLensky через svg? я видел этот макет уже, думал как это сделать самому, без библиотек, только на js что-то придумывать и чтобы было адаптивно

Comment: @МихаилКамахин ну конечно на svg -он автоматом резиновый

Comment: @МихаилКамахин  https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/eYpegOB